# How to make two HTML element align in single line?

Tags: html, css

I have two HTML element in one row. Whoch should display something like this:
[image]

For that I made both the element display-inline and also I set float left and right respectively. But they are displaying something like this:
[image]

You can see they are not being aligned properly.

```css
.selected-account{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    color: #0679ca;
}

.select-account-accordion{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    color: #0679ca;
}
```

```html
<div id="select-account" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 disabled-billing-accordion">
         <h3 id="select-acct" class="select-account-accordion">Select Account(s)</h3>
         <span id="account-selected" class="selected-account">0 of 8 account selected</span> 
        </div>
```

Can you please suggest on this?

Edit: I think because I put those two element in the div class which I put for creating accordion, so thats why its creating trouble. Please see the style below for that div which is having class "disabled-billing-accordion"

```
.disabled-billing-accordion h3::before{
            background: url("/static/img/accordion.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            background-position: -1px -97px;
            content: " ";
            width: 34px;
            height: 34px;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25px;
            margin-left: 1em
        }

    .disabled-billing-accordion h3{
        padding: .2em 0 0 3em;
        color: #0679ca;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        line-height: 2.1875em;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        font-weight: 100 !important

    }

.disabled-billing-accordion{
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bdbdbd
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HI now you can define `margin:0;` and `line-height`  as like this

```css
.selected-account{
    float: right;
    color: #0679ca;
  margin:0;
  line-height:20px;
}

.select-account-accordion{
    float: left;
    color: #0679ca;
  margin:0;
  line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="select-account" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 disabled-billing-accordion">
         <h3 id="select-acct" class="select-account-accordion">Select Account(s)</h3>
         <span id="account-selected" class="selected-account">0 of 8 account selected</span> 
        </div>
```

Comment: it didnt work for me.. may be because I have put these both element inside a div that has class "disabled-billing-accordion". This class is responsible for displaying accordion.

Answer (score 0):

There is margin for h3. Try

```
#select-acct {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not working. Please see the Edit in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use position:fixed and add left:"width of first one"
Like,

```
div1{
position:fixed;
width:200px;
height:300px;
}
div2{
position:fixed;
left:200px;
width:200px;
height:300px;
}
```

Hope it will help.

**Edit**

I have added some inline css in your code with `position:fixed` Here is screen shot.

[image]

Comment: It is not working. Please see the Edit in my question

Answer (score 0):

if you use h3 it will take default some margin and line-height if u check in the image while inspect u can see ,reference https://plnkr.co/edit/3O4773wA10jV1tC92zik?p=preview

So u have to add the styles for margin and line-height

```
.selected-account{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    color: #0679ca;
    margin:0;
    line-height:20px;
}

.select-account-accordion{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    line-height:20px;
    margin:0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working. Please see the Edit in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the `float: left;` property from h3 ie,

```
.select-account-accordion {
    display: inline;
    /* float: left; */ //Remove this line
    color: #0679ca;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either reduce `margin-top: 0px;` for
`<h3 id="select-acct" class="select-account-accordion">Select Account(s)</h3>`
or
add equivalent margin-top example `margin-top: 20px` for
`<span id="account-selected" class="selected-account">0 of 8 account selected</span>`

```css
.selected-account{
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    color: #0679ca;
}

.select-account-accordion{
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    color: #0679ca;
}
```

```html
<div id="select-account" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 disabled-billing-accordion">
         <h3 id="select-acct" class="select-account-accordion">Select Account(s)</h3>
         <span id="account-selected" class="selected-account">0 of 8 account selected</span> 
        </div>
```